# Align label on top of the bootstrap Toggle Switch

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using three bootstrap toggle switch which I need to align side by side and corresponding label top of these. And also I require those switch are in same level as all of other my inputs (textbox/dropdown) are. I am very bad at CSS so I couldn't able to get it right. Here what I want: [image]

```html
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    //input fields
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>IsFeatured</label>
    <label class="switch">
      <input type="checkbox" checked>
      <span class="slider round"></span>
    </label>
    <label>IsNew</label>
    <label class="switch">
      <input type="checkbox" checked>
      <span class="slider round"></span>
    </label>
    <label>IsReturnable</label>
    <label class="switch">
      <input type="checkbox" checked>
      <span class="slider round"></span>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see that you are using Bootstrap in your page so you don't really need to write extra CSS to achieve this design.All you need to add some bootstrap classes in right order for your alignment.

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="form-group">
         <label>Test1</label>
         <div>
             <label class="switch">
                <input type="checkbox" checked>
                <span class="slider round"></span>
             </label>
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="form-group">
         <label>Test2</label>
         <div>
             <label class="switch">
                 <input type="checkbox" checked>
                 <span class="slider round"></span>
          </label>
     </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="form-group">
         <label>Test3</label>
         <div>
             <label class="switch">
                 <input type="checkbox" checked>
                 <span class="slider round"></span>
          </label>
     </div>
</div>
```

Hopefully that will help

[image: Output]

Comment: thanks, it works, But I had to some workout along with your answer. my input fields right under the toggle ware going down.  @Ziaul

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xsm-12">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>IsFeatured</label>
        <div>
            <label class="switch">
                <input type="checkbox" checked"><span class="slider round "></span></label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xsm-12 ">
    <div class="form-group ">
        <label>IsNew</label>
        <div>
            <label class="switch ">
                <input type="checkbox " checked><span class="slider round "></span></label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xsm-12 ">
    <div class="form-group ">
        <label>IsReturnable</label<div>
            <label class="switch ">
                <input type="checkbox " checked><span class="slider round "></span></label>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Just use the grid system.